# How to add onSuccess to React-Query mutation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

This is a classic way for a POST request with React-Query:

```
   import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
    
    import { IUploadFieldRequest } from '../constants/types';
    import { licenseServiceAPI } from '../services';
    
    export const URI = () => '/licenses/upload';
    
    export const useUploadLicense = () => {
      const queryClient = useQueryClient();
      const [apiService] = licenseServiceAPI<FormData>({
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
    
      const {
        data: response,
        mutateAsync,
        isLoading,
        isSuccess
      } = useMutation((formData: IUploadFieldRequest) => apiService.post(URI(), formData), {
          onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries('test');
      });
    
      return {
        data: response,
        mutateAsync,
        isLoading,
        isSuccess
      };
    };
    
    export default useUploadLicense;
```

The problem is that I need to do some changes to it, to parse the array and append its data, so I've done it like this:

```
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

import { IUploadFieldRequest } from '../constants/types';
import { licenseServiceAPI } from '../services';

export const URI = () => '/licenses/upload';

export const useUploadLicense = () => {
  const [apiService] = licenseServiceAPI<FormData>({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  });

  const {
    data: response,
    mutateAsync,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
  } = useMutation((formData: IUploadFieldRequest) => {
    const form = new FormData();
    Array.from(formData.files)?.forEach((file) => {
      form.append('license-file', file);
    });

    return apiService.post(URI(), form);
  });

  return {
    data: response?.data,
    uploadFiles: mutateAsync,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
  };
};

export default useUploadLicense;
```

It works fine but don't know where and how to add `onSuccess`, is it possible in this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Parameter second of useMutation is object has `onSucess`,`onErrors`

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations#mutation-side-effects

```
 const {
    data: response,
    mutateAsync,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess
    } = useMutation((formData: IUploadFieldRequest) => {
            const form = new FormData();
            Array.from(formData.files)?.forEach((file) => {
                form.append('license-file', file);
            }, {
                onSuccess: (data) => {
                    //your code here
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
```